# Cannot resolve module 'babel' after installing babel; nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I am trying to run webpack as just `webpack` and I am getting:

```
  ERROR in multi main
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'babel-loader' in /home/cchilders/CodeTutorials/build-react-starter/client
 @ multi main
```

it seems to think it should resolve in the `client` folder, but I want it to find packages in `node_modules`. My webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');

var config = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
  entry: [
    './main.js',
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'www'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    root: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    root: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    ],
  },
};
module.exports = config;
```

The project is at `git clone git@bitbucket.org:servandoavila1/codetutorials.git`

### Edit

The tutorial was outdated and used babel, babel-loaders is required.

Changing the `module.loaders` to `babel-loader` from `babel` and install the loader worked.

Comment: Did you install [`babel`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel) (mentioned in the title) or [`babel-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-loader) (mentioned in the snippets)?

Comment: Have you tried removing `context` key from your webpack config file? you're setting your app root path to `./client`. Just found [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1606).

Comment: `context` wasn't an issue; I got other errors and deleted node modules then reinstalled...the tutorial was outdated and used `babel`, `babel-loaders` is required. thank you